# I want to compile java file in ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I want to compile java file in ubuntu.

```
package com.amazonaws.services.s3 does not exist
cannot find symbol
```

But, this error occurs.
I made a lib folder in a project folder and put jar files in it. In addition, there are Server.java files and ServerThread.java files in the Projects folder.
So I've been working on a project folder.

```
javac -cp ".:./lib/*.jar" Server.java ServerThread.java
```

I did this.
However, an error occurs. I think the reason is that the jar file is not recognized.
It worked well in Eclipse.
How can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

May be that class belongs to a jar file which is distributed separately to AWS SDK. But usually To compile a java file in Ubuntu:
open your terminal (In project folder) and type:

```
javac filename.java
```

To run the generated class file, use:

```
java filename
```

But to do this you need to have the Java JDK installed and configured in your computer.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the file can be compiled only if the jar file is included in the code... There is an error in including jar file.